# GET node without loop on XML response

Tags: asp-classic

i have a xml response like that:

```
<result><message>Email does not exist</message></result>
```

i just wanna get the text of the message node "Email does not exist".

Im using "MSXML2.DOMDocument" component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
node = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/result/message").innerText
```